# data table fnDraw no recarga la tabla

Tags: laravel, datatables

sucede que estoy obteniendo mi información vía ajax y lo plasmo con jquery en mi datatable pero al momento de agregar un registro no recarga la tabla solo si refresco la pagina aparecen los nuevos datos.
he usado fnDraw y ajax.reload. pero ninguno parece funcionar si me podrían ayudar se los agradecería.

Comment: No sé si te servirá esto, pero aquí tienes una pregunta que más o menos pregunta lo mismo que tú https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event

Answer (score 0):

prueba con `$('#miTabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();`  después de insertar, eliminar o editar la tabla.

Un saludo